# Making a custom SharePoint List JSON View Format that can automatically display new columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have created a JSON view format in a SharePoint List for a client. They anticipate that in the future they will be adding additional columns to the list, but they do not have the in-house expertise to format their own views and would like to keep their reliance on us or third parties to a minimum. Is there a way to create a view format that is able to handle future columns without modifying the JSON?

I have looked through Microsoft's documentation on list formatting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference) and various forums but have not found anything that quite fits this requirement. The closest thing I have seen is the forEach property that allows you to assign formats to the possible values of a multi-choice column. It would be nice if there was a way to loop through the columns in the way that forEach allows you to loop through the choices of multi-choice columns. However, I don't want to assume that the solution looks like that or even involves JSON formatting. I am open to any suggestions or other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SharePoint Online JSON formatting does not support such customizations that will automatically display new columns in the JSON view formatting.

SharePoint site/list owner will have to add new columns in the list, show new columns in list view and then customize the existing JSON view format to include the new columns in JSON by referring them using their [internal names](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

There is no SharePoint out of the box way to add new columns to JSON view format automatically. There is card designer for tiles/gallery view which allows users to easily select columns and include them in the standard JSON view format for tiles. But, if you have used your own customized JSON for view formatting, using card designer will overwrite those customizations.

**Microsoft Documentations**:

1. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)
2. [SharePoint JSON formatting syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)

Comment: Agree with Ganesh Sanap. JSON formatting needs to be set manually.